# PHP. Building a drop down menu . Passing around object array is sloppy how do I simplify this

Tags: php

I'm trying to grasp OOP and I decided to build a site that accesses a sql database.
It's been working out great so far I have several tables, but I've run into a snag

I access the database and create an object array with

```
$Dog_array = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Dog');
```

Simplified but my class looks like this.

```
class Dog {
     private $name;

     function get_name {
     return $this->name;
    }
```

list that build my table

```
function edit_table($Dog) {

echo "<table><tr><form action='update.php' method ='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $id ."'>";

echo "<td>". $Dog->get_id() ."</td>";
?>
<td><input type='text' name='rname' value="<?php echo $Dog->get_rname(); ?>"></td>
<td><input type='text' name='cname' value="<?php echo $Dog->get_cname(); ?>"></td>
<td><input type='text' name='dob' value="<?php echo $Dog->get_dob(); ?>"></td>
<td><input type='radio' name='gender' value='male' <?PHP if($Dog->get_gender() == 'male'){ echo "checked=\"checked\""; } ?> /> Male
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='female' <?PHP if($Dog->get_gender() == 'female'){ echo "checked=\"checked\""; } ?> />Female</td>
<td><input type='text' name='sire' value="<?PHP echo "builddropdown" ?> "></td>
<td><input type='text' name='dam' value="<?PHP drop_menu() ?>"></td>
<?php

if ($Dog->get_available()) {
    $checked = "checked=\"checked\"";
} else {
    $checked = NULL;
echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\"" . $checked . "name=\"available\" value=\"TRUE\"/></td>";

if ($Dog->get_display()) {
    $checked = "checked=\"checked\"";
} else {
    $checked = NULL;
}
echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\"" . $checked . "name=\"display\" value=\"TRUE\"/></td></tr></table>";
?>
<input type='submit' value='change image'/></form>
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="upload.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Change Image Thumb">
</FORM>
<input type='submit' value='change image'/></form>
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="upload.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Change Image Thumb">
</FORM>
    <?php
    }
?>
<input type='submit' value='update'/></form>
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="index.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Back">
</FORM>
<?php 
}

?>
```

My drop down

```
function drop_menu() {

?>
<form name ="dropdown">
<select ="alldogs">
<?php
        foreach ($Dog_array as $Dogs) { 
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $Dogs->get_id() . "\">" . $Dogs->get_rname();   ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</form>
<? }
```

My drop down menu creates a list of all of the dogs.

I get the error Invalid argument supplied for foreach

I get why I get the error I just don't know how to clean this up so I don't have to pass my Object array into my edit_table function so I can pass it into drop down function
.
I thought about creating a child class but the menu is built from an array of the objects not one object so I don't know how to make this work either. New to forum posting, so feel free to recommend some corrections in how I ask for help.

Comment: Either you pass the `$Dog_array` or get it as some global are the two ways I see this happening. Apart from this please check your html - 1) `drop_menu` call inside input 2) `drop_menu` definition closing the `form`, not starting the `select`

Comment: What do you mean by get as some global?

Comment: I think I corrected the html but I haven't looked it in great detail what exactly do you mean by "call inside input"

Comment: from "call inside input" i mean this line (which is not correct i think) - `<input type='text' name='dam' value="<?PHP drop_menu() ?>">`  and from "some global" i mean use a global variable to have `$dog_array` available inside `drop_menu` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with the arrage $Dog_array scope.
You need to pass the $Dog_array to the drop_menu function.

```
<?php
function drop_menu($Dog_array) {

?>
<form name ="dropdown">
<select ="alldogs">
<?php
foreach ($Dog_array as $Dogs) { 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $Dogs->get_id() . "\">" . $Dogs->get_rname();   ?>></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</form>
<? }
```

And whenever you need to call the function, pass the array normally.

Also you can pass by reference

```
<?php
function drop_menu(&$Dog_array) {?>
```

In this case any manipulation to the array inside the function will impact the original array directly.

Comment: Thank you for answering what is wrong with the code that does make sense to do. However, my question is because this function is being called by another function. Is there a better way to do this? I'm currently looking into http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php maybe this will give me some better answers on a "better" way. I want to point out I'm still trying to grasp OOP.

Comment: This depends on your application. To pass the array there are three ways. 1) Pass a copy of it as mentioned in my first example. This is used when you do not need to impact the main array and keep it intact, and the amount of data passed is not huge. 2) Pass it by reference, this is used when you need to manipulate the main array without making it accessible by all functions. 3) The third way is to define the array as GLOBAL, i.e. it will be accessible through all you scripts and any included scripts, this is not recommended in some cases, as a wrong call my impact the wrong array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function dropdown( $name, array $options, $selected=null )
{

    //array_push($options, "");

    /*** begin the select ***/

    //<select name="dropdownarray" id="dropdownarray">
    $dropdown = '<select name="'.$name.'" id="'.$name.'">';
    $selected = $selected;
    /*** loop over the options ***/

      echo  "<b>$name : </b>";  // Title

     $dropdown .= '<option value=></option>'."\n"; //empty data


    foreach( $options as $key=>$option )
    {
        /*** assign a selected value ***/
        $select = $selected==$key ? ' selected' : null;

        /*** add each option to the dropdown ***/
        $dropdown .= '<option value="'.$key.'"'.$select.'>'.$option.'</option>'."\n";
    }

    /*** close the select ***/
    $dropdown .= '</select>'."\n";


    /*** and return the completed dropdown ***/
    return $dropdown;
}

enter code here
```